# Closing dropdown by clicking outside in Javascript (tutorial clarification)

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have attempted to implement the method of opening and closing a drop-down using Javascript via [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp) tutorial on w3schools.com. While the function to "show" the drop-down works, the one to close it does not. Furthermore, there is no explanation alongside this code to explain why it *should* work, making it difficult to debug.

```
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My questions are, therefore,

1) whether the code in the tutorial *should* work for the purpose of closing the drop-down. (ANSWERED)

2) Could someone please clarify how/why this should work, for the sake of clarity for myself and future newbies who make come across the same tutorial and issue? (UNANSWERED)

Edit (MY ATTEMPT):

HTML:

```
<div class="sharedown">     
    <p onclick="shareVis()" class="sharebtn">&nbsp Share</p>
    <div id="mySharedown" class="sharedown-content">
        <a href="#">Self</a>
        <p>User</p><input type="text" name="user-name" placeholder="Share to">
        <a href="#">Community</a>
    </div> 
</div>
```

JS:

```
function shareVis() {
    document.getElementById("mySharedown").className = "show";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('sharebtn')) {

        var sharedowns = document.getElementsByClassName("sharedown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < sharedowns.length; i++) {
            var openSharedown = sharedowns[i];
            if (openSharedown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openSharedown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

CSS:

```
/* Share dropdown menu */

p.sharebtn {

    color: darkgrey;
    font-family:calibri;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 12;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    display:    inline; 
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
p.sharebtn:hover, p.sharebtn:focus {
    color: grey;

}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.sharedown {
    position: relative;
    display:    inline-block;
```

}

```
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.sharedown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:   #f1f1f1;
    min-width:  100px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 1px #C4E3F5;
    z-index:1; /* place dropdown infront of everything else*/
}

.sharedown-content a { 
color: black;
padding: 5px 5px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-
content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:   #f1f1f1;
    min-width:  100px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 1px #C4E3F5;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index:1;}
```

Comment: kindly provide the HTML to tell you where is the exact problem ? because the example in w3schools is fully functional

Comment: what says the debugging console in the browser?

Comment: No errors from console

Comment: can you add your css?

Comment: `document.getElementById("mySharedown").className = "show";` *overwrites* the classname. It no longer has the class `sharedown-content`, so when `window.onclick` fires the `sharedowns` variable will be empty.

Comment: It turns out I caused the error myself by changing it from `classList.toggle("show")` to `className = "show"` while attempting to debug a different error (lack of closing parenthesis).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue lies in `shareVis` function. Here

```
document.getElementById("mySharedown").className = "show";
```

you are replacing `#mySharedown` class name to `show`. Then in `window.onclick`

```
var sharedowns = document.getElementsByClassName("sharedown-content");
```

you are not getting any `sharedowns` as you already replaced the class name to `show`.

---

You can either add `show` class into `classList`

```
document.getElementById("mySharedown").classList.add("show");
```

or replace the class name with `sharedown-content show`

```
document.getElementById("mySharedown").className = "sharedown-content show";
```

Working solution below:

```js
function shareVis() {
    //document.getElementById("mySharedown").className = "sharedown-content show";
    document.getElementById("mySharedown").classList.add("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.sharebtn')) {

        var sharedowns = document.getElementsByClassName("sharedown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < sharedowns.length; i++) {
            var openSharedown = sharedowns[i];
            if (openSharedown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openSharedown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("mySharedown").addEventListener('click',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
#mySharedown{
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#mySharedown.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="sharedown">     
    <p onclick="shareVis()" class="sharebtn">&nbsp Share</p>
    <div id="mySharedown" class="sharedown-content">
        <a href="#">Self</a>
        <p>User</p><input type="text" name="user-name" placeholder="Share to">
        <a href="#">Community</a>
    </div> 
</div>
```

### Update

To prevent the second click within `#mySharedown` from hiding `#mySharedown`, you should add another `click` event for `#mySharedown` and prevent it from bubbling up, like this

```
document.getElementById("mySharedown").addEventListener('click',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Updates are included in the working solution

Comment: The drop-down now stays open; however it closes when I click anywhere, including inside of it. Any help?

Comment: Do you want to close it after another click on **Share** button?

Comment: I want it to close after clicking anyway except within in the menu itself.

Comment: The update worked perfectly. Now my dropdown is working as I want. However, I still do not quite understand how the `function(event)` and contained for loop is working to this effect (also part of my original question). Perhaps I'll do some digging into the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Update 2022
Vanilla Javascript now contains a mehtod called Node.closest(Node) to check if the event matches the node in the upper hierarchy. below is an example to open the dropdown menu on click and hide it again on click and if clicking outside the document will also hide the dropdown menu.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('.list')
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')

btn.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
  
 list.classList.toggle('hidden')
  e.stopPropagation()
})

document.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
  if(e.target.closest('.list')) return 
  
  list.classList.add('hidden')

})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display:none
}
ul {
  background-color: blue;
  
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">open</button>
<ul class="list hidden">
    <li class="item1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item3">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example is fully functional and should work. Copy the following code below:

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
    toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
    }
    
    // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
          var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
          if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
            openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
 .dropbtn {
        background-color: #3498DB;
        color: white;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
        background-color: #2980B9;
    }
    
    .dropdown {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        min-width: 160px;
        overflow: auto;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a {
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
    }
    
    .dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd}
    
    .show {display:block;}
```

```html
    
    <h2>Clickable Dropdown</h2>
    <p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
    
    <div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
      <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I leave another "short" example that I implemented to my own code, but is easy to understand.

.tw-hidden is a class "display: none"

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
        let customDropdownsEl = document.querySelectorAll(".custom-dropdown");
        let liContainerEl = event.target.querySelector(".custom-dropdown");
    
        customDropdownsEl.forEach(el => el.parentNode !== event.target && !el.classList.contains("tw-hidden") && el.classList.add("tw-hidden"));
        event.target.matches('.custom-dropdown-container') && liContainerEl.classList.toggle("tw-hidden");
}
```