# if(!event.target.matches) anything but multiple divs - Js invertion logic

Tags: javascript

I have an input field (.dropbtn) which shows a drop-down (.dropdown-content2) when selected. I use the following code to close the dropdown when anything but the input field is clicked:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
...
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content2");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to make it so the dropdown closes if anything except the input field or the dropdown itself is clicked. When the dropdown is clicked I want to add a class, and if it contains already contains this class, close it.

This way the dropdown closes after it is clicked twice.

I'm having some trouble figuring out how the invertion (!) thing works and was wondering if "else if" would work in this scenario.

*Edit: I tried adding another event target using:

```
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn') && !event.target.matches('.dropdown-content2')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content2");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
```

I also tried using !event.target.closest() instead of .matches()

Answer (score 0):

Using event.stopPropagation worked.

```
document.getElementById("myDropdown5").addEventListener('click',function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Closing dropdown by clicking outside in Javascript (tutorial clarification)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50465697/closing-dropdown-by-clicking-outside-in-javascript-tutorial-clarification/50466211)